# trying to build a simple JS web UI to post data to MongoDB. Some advice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been playing with and learning JS for a few months and have built some dynamic text changing sites. Long story short I my wife has a need for a simple tool she can post client account info in and search later with notes. There's a lot of things that can do this but I want to use it as a reason to learn Node.js and work on more JS stuff.

All the back-end things I could easily do in Python but I don't really know how to bridge JS to python so I figured I'd just use a native JS back-end instead.

Upon searching I'm seeing a lot of JS frameworks and now I'm sort of lost.
I have my db set up and a bunch of servers, but what is the best framework I should use to:

1. authenticate a user
2. fill out a form and save the data to mongodb
3. be able to search said data and retrieve the results in a list

I don't really need any code help at this time, I just don't want to spend 3 weeks learning React only to find out Node was easier and better for this application.

Thanks.

Comment: I answered your question with my "way to go" stack, but I just want to say that the "best" framework is something very personal. All frameworks have their caveats, we generally will choose the one we can work comfortably with. 
I have been working with the MERN Stack and I really love it, I even use it in some production products and in some internal solutions I create for our company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/) and [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) for that.

For the Frontend, since it is something simple, you can try React and use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) to generate the starter boilerplate.

With Node.js on the backend, you can also use an npm package called [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) to connect and do all MongoDB operations.

If you need authentication, [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) can simplify that for you.

For the UI you can use [MaterialUI](https://mui.com/)

For simple small projects, this is my way to go, if you need help later you can also ping me I would be happy to help.

Comment: thanks man! really helpful. I dont know why my question was closed or why we cant ask for opinions on this site from the advanced and expert users but I appreciate your response. I was thinking node and I saw some sample code for mongoose thats easy to follow. never heard of passport or materialui til now. Theres so many things.. hence my ask. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your need actually a mongodb client GUI?

Better not reinvent the wheel and rely on battle tested solutions to manage the users (always touchy because of GDPR regulations).

A quick web search led me to https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass but there are plenty of such tools for free.

Comment: hey no. i have compass and mongodb works fine.... 
i need to create a form that posts the entered data to *SOMETHING* and that something will then enter the data recived from the form to mongodb in the backend.

The *SOMETHING* to handle the request on the back end is my need.